# Show vertical line on hover in R Shiny dashboard

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard

I would like to make a Shiny dashboard with e.g. a simple line chart like the one in the top left panel on this website:

https://inflation.ihs.ac.at

I know how to make the plot with `ggplot2` and how to make a Shiny dashboard to display the graph (and different versions of it when inputs in the ui are changed).

However, I do not know how to include the vertical line that follows your cursor and how to display labels and values when you hover over certain values.

My question: Is it possible to make a dashboard like this without having knowledge of CSS/Java/some other programming language than R? I looked at the `dygraph` package which helped me program something similar to the dashboard on the website above but I am not sure if it includes the possibility to make specific adjustments to the hover options provided.

Ideally I would like to be able to specify the detailed hover options (length, width and color of the line and the labels/values, etc.) and still be able to make the original plot with `ggplot2` which is obviously not the case if I plot my data using the `dygraph` package. Is that an option?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want but close, with **rAmCharts4**:

```r
library(rAmCharts4)

dat <- data.frame(
  x = 1:10,
  y = rnorm(10)
)

amLineChart(
  data = dat,
  xValue = "x",
  yValues = "y",
  alwaysShowBullets = TRUE,
  cursor = list(axes = "x")
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. How "customizable" are those graphs compared to ggplot2? Can you change everything like line width, line type, grid lines, title and subtitle, legend, etc.?

Comment: @r-newbie Check the examples given in the package. There are many possible customizations.